# Memcached expiration of keys

Tags: memcached

When you set a key to expire in `memcached` does it actually get deleted when the expiration is up, or does it get deleted once the key is requested (`get`) and expiration has expired. In other words, does expiration automatically delete the value from memcached, or simply flag it as expired?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expiration is lazy. If you do a get on an expired key it is deleted. Otherwise it is flagged and when you run out of space in your cache it will be removed to make room for a new item.

Comment: Along with above mentioned lazy expiration technique, post 1.5.0, a crawler periodically scans the cache and frees expired objects. - https://github.com/memcached/memcached/wiki/UserInternals#when-memory-is-reclaimed